# What does the second argument of a gulp task mean:

Tags: gulp

I'm looking for an answer to this, doesn't have to be in depth or great detail. Just want to know exactly what happening with the sequence of the task.

```
gulp.task('name',['*this right here*'], function() {
    // content
});
```

Does it mean do this task in consecutively namely with this definition task? Why this came up for me is because in my gulpfile.js I'm using [gulp-inject](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject) for app files and [wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep) for vendor dependencies. If this is wrong or either one will do then great, Im under the impression not though. What I have so far is below.

```
//originally i didn't have bower here in the array in 2nd param.
gulp.task('index', ['bower'], function() {
  var target = gulp.src(files.app_files.target);
  var sources = gulp.src(files.app_files.sources, {
    read: false
  });

  return target.pipe(inject(sources))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});


gulp.task('bower', function() {
  return gulp
    .src(files.app_files.target)
    .pipe(wiredep())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});


<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example Page</title>
  <!-- Vendor Files  -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- App Files -->
  <!-- inject:css -->
  <!-- endinject -->
</head>

<body>
  <navigation></navigation>
  <div ui-view></div>
  <footer-area></footer-area>
  <!-- Vendor Files -->
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- App Files -->
  <!-- inject:js -->
  <!-- endinject -->
</body>
```

**Update**

```
gulp.task('index', function() {
  var target = gulp.src(files.app_files.target);
  // It's not necessary to read the files (will speed up things), we're only after their paths:
  var sources = gulp.src(files.app_files.sources, {
    read: false
  });

  return target
    //here instead of breaking into new task i piped inject and wiredep, works great
    .pipe(inject(sources))
    .pipe(wiredep())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's an array of tasks to run before your task.
Also, note those tasks (all the ones in the array, in you case there's only `bower`) run in parallel.

If you need some in sequence. Consider `gulp-sequence`

Comment: Okay simple enough, would you recommend I point one task at the dist/index file so as to finish injecting files on same page.

Comment: Nevermind, i got it. I just ened up piping in same task. See above update for what I came to realize with your help! Thank you.